Django admin panel not loading css/js on digitalocean server
Running into a problem where in my localhost things are working great with this structure:
localhost
But on digitalocean server I got this structure:
server
Notice how on the server I got an extra static folder called 'staticfiles'.
On my localhost it's working great but at the server level my admin panel can't seem to find the right css/js because it is looking for the files inside the static folder.
These are my settings file:
`BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(file)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]`
I am not using a droplet but the app platform option.
Any ideas to help me?
